# Writting a boolean method with float array and a boolean as parameters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop, boolean

I have to write a program that checks if the numbers in the array are in a ascending order or not. I wrote the code but i get this error back. I have to somehow implement both parameters

```
boolean isSorted(float[] numbers, boolean ascending){
    //tell if the numbers are ascending (ascending == true), or not (ascending == false)
    boolean s=ascending;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            s= numbers[i] < numbers[1+i];
    }
    return s;
}

boolean a=isSorted(new float[]{1,7,8,9,10,14},true);
System.out.println(a);
```

this is the error i get back

```
created method isSorted(float[],boolean)
|  Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
|        at isSorted (#7:5)
|        at (#9:1)
true
```

Comment: `it compiles` are you sure? According to your edit, it doesn't

Comment: you never pass in a boolean when you call it. You'd need to do `boolean a=isSorted(new float[]{1,7,8,9,10,14}, true);` (or false)

Comment: The error message you posted tells you what's happening.  It found `float[]`, but expected `float[], boolean`

Comment: Once your `i` reached `numbers.length - 1`, `1 + i` will trigger AIOOBE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting run time exception(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) because in the last iteration of the for loop, interpreter is trying to access an element which does not exists (numbers[1+i]), so keeping an if condition before this logic will do the trick as below

```
boolean  isSorted(float[] numbers, boolean ascending){
    //tell if the numbers are ascending (ascending == true), or not (ascending == false)
    boolean s=ascending;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        //added this if condition to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        if(i == numbers.length-1){
            continue;
        }
        s= numbers[i] < numbers[1+i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error back even though I basically copy pasted this code

Comment: have you updated the isSorted() function like provided in the answer or only the first line ?

Comment: sorry my bad i just realized the mistake, let me update the answer for you